# Console.log not displaying anything in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, api, google-chrome, console.log

This is my code. I am trying to check if I am able to get the data from the api. Putting the api url in the browser shows the json data but console.log does not show anything.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#lesotho').click(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=lesotho",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
    request.done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If you check the console after making the request you can see the error: `Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with`

Comment: why are you passing url in url in "url" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method 'done' is calling when having successful AJAX response.

so, try this

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://universities.hipolabs.com/search? country=lesotho", 
  dataType: "jsonp"
})
request.done(function(data){
    console.log( data );
});
request.fail(function(xhr,status){
    console.log( xhr );
    console.log( status );
});
```

another way(i recommend this code) is

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://universities.hipolabs.com/search? country=lesotho", 
  dataType: "jsonp" ,
  success : function(data){
    console.log( data );
  },
  error : function(xhr , status){
    console.log( status );
    console.log( xhr );
  }
});
```

then, you can see the log.